# How do I make classes from a submodule available in a parent module's namespace?

Tags: python, import, module, namespaces, package

Here's a python module. `foo` is in `sys.path`.

```
foo\
    __init__.py
    bar\
        __init__.py
        base.py
            class Base(object)
        derived.py
            import foo.bar.base as base
            class Derived(base.Base)
```

I've got nothing fancy going on yet. If I want to instantiate the **Derived** class from the `derived` module, I can do that easily enough:

```
import foo.bar.derived as derived
print(derived.Derived())
```

However, I'd like to just import the `bar` module and call `bar.Derived()`, because I plan to have lots of classes within lots of different modules, and I don't want to deal with all these tentacular import paths. My understanding is that I can simply import **Derived** into the namespace of the `bar` module, by modifying my project like so:

```
foo\
    __init__.py
    bar\
        __init__.py
            from foo.bar.derived import Derived
        base.py
            class Base(object)
        derived.py
            import foo.bar.base as base
            class Derived(base.Base)
```

Now I should be able to do the following:

```
import foo.bar as bar
print(bar.Derived())
```

But I get an AttributeError complaining that the `foo` module has no submodule called `bar`:

```
test.py             (1): import foo.bar
foo\bar\__init__.py (1): from foo.bar.derived import Derived
foo\bar\derived.py  (1): import foo.bar.base as base

AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'bar'
```

In fact, my original test code (at top) doesn't work either! As soon as I try to import `foo.bar`, I get errors.

What I can gleam from this error is that the import statement in `__init__.py` causes `derived.py` to be executed before `bar` is fully loaded, and therefore it can't import the module (also from `bar`) which contains its own base class. I'm coming from the C++ world, where ultra-nested namespaces aren't as integral and a simple forward declaration would negate this problem, but I've been led to believe that what I'm looking for is possible and at least a somewhat acceptably Pythonic solution. What am I doing wrong? What's the correct way to make classes from a submodule available in the parent module's namespace?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you're working with Python 2.5 or later, try using explicit relative imports (http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0328/#guido-s-decision):

```
test.py             (1): import foo.bar
foo\bar\__init__.py (1): from .derived import Derived
foo\bar\derived.py  (1): from . import base
```

(Note that if you are indeed working with Python 2.5 or 2.6, you'll need to include `from __future__ import absolute_import` in your modules.)

Answer (score 1):

in derived.py, use this:

**EDIT**: as JAB pointed out, implicit relative imports are *deprecated*, to the following isn't recommended (although it does work still in Python 2.7 - with no deprecation errors!).

<del>import base  # this is all you need - it's in the current directory</del>

Instead, use:

```
from . import base #
```

**(or)**

```
from foo.bar import base
```

**instead of:**

```
import foo.bar.base as base
```

This will solve both your errors (since they're from the same issue).  Your import doesn't work since there is no `base` function or class inside the foo.bar.base module.

Comment: Implicitly relative imports are deprecated at this point in time, so I'd say it's better not to use them unless you have to (i.e. you're working with versions of Python older than 2.5).

Comment: @JAB: `base` is in the same directory as `derived`.  Are you saying that `import base` (importing a module in the same directory) is **deprecated** ??

Comment: "In Python 2.6, any `import` statement that results in an intra-package import will raise `DeprecationWarning` (this also applies to `from <> import` that fails to use the relative import syntax)." I don't have a copy of Python 2.6 set up on this computer to test it with, but I'd bet that it would do so. Also, see http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0328/#rationale-for-absolute-imports

Comment: Er, awforsythe was trying to use `import foo.bar.base as base`, not `from foo.bar.base import base`.

Comment: @JAB: I've carefully read that (& other sources), and I can see that just a raw `import base` isn't the right thing to do.  Thanks for the enlightenment!... +1 ...it does work however...and without any deprecation warnings either (on Python 2.7).  I'm not really sure why, since it isn't on my sys.path.

Comment: It may be that the deprecation warning only occurs in Python 2.6 when using `from __future__ import absolute_import`. Lots of people use Python 2.7 to execute programs written for older versions of Python, and with 2.7 having absolute imports active by default (though still supporting the old implicit style for intra-package imports) those programs that utilized old-style intra-package imports would result in the deprecation warning all the time rather than only when specifically choosing to utilize absolute imports. That's what I'm thinking the reasoning was. I might be completely wrong.